# Fluently calling await without parentheses

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to refactor this line

```
var result = (await Foo()).Bar()
```

So that it doesn't use parentheses and don't assign await result to temp variable?

I'm trying to build a fluent framework that supports long operations and real world code turns pretty ugly when you need to enclose await in parentheses:

```
var result = (await collection
    .TransformElements()
    .FetchData())
    .ProcessResults()
    .Aggregate();
```

Comment: any particular reason you don't like the temp variable approach? it would be very clean and obvious. IMO much cleaner than a huge single expression... Minor note: I wonder if `FetchData()` should be `FetchDataAsync()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a fluent async inferface in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32112418/how-to-make-a-fluent-async-inferface-in-c-sharp)